# How to send content of a variable from one form to another form using java

Tags: java, forms, global-variables, getter-setter

Here is my entire block of codes, the DrawForm is used to draw rectangles, ellipses etc..  when i am drawing the ellipses it counts the number of ellipses and save it to an array and print the size of the array as soon as the ellipse is drawn. So what i want is to use the variable "sizes" that is used to get the size of the array and send it to "AttributeForm" and make my IF-Statement on it.

```html
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class DrawForm extends JFrame {
    private int len;
    
  // public int getSizes(){
 // return len;
//}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -140274271716086522L;

    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu File, Exit;
    JMenuItem New, Open;
    JComponent DrawingBoard;

    JButton  lineBut, ellipseBut, rectBut, strokeBut;

    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    // Contains all of the rules for drawing

    Graphics2D graphSettings;

   
    // Going to be used to monitor what shape to draw next

    int currentAction = 1;

    // Transparency of the shape

    // Default stroke and fill colors

    Color strokeColor = Color.BLACK;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawForm();
    }

    public DrawForm() {
        // Define the defaults for the JFrame

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setTitle("ERD BUILDER");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Add the menubar to the frame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Define and add two drop down menu to the menubar
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu dbMenu = new JMenu("Database");
        JMenu ToolsMenu = new JMenu("Tools");
        JMenu HelpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(dbMenu);
        menuBar.add(ToolsMenu);
        menuBar.add(HelpMenu);
        // Create and add simple menu item to one of the drop down menu
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        JMenuItem UndoAction = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        JMenuItem RedoAction = new JMenuItem("Redo");
        JMenuItem clearAction = new JMenuItem("Clear");
        JMenuItem saveAction = new JMenuItem("Save");
        JMenuItem exportAction = new JMenuItem("Export");
        JMenuItem printAction = new JMenuItem("Print");
        JMenuItem ConvertAction = new JMenuItem("Convert To Tables");
        JMenuItem ColorAction = new JMenuItem("Color Picker");
        JMenuItem ZoomAction = new JMenuItem("Zoom");
        JMenuItem EntityAction = new JMenuItem("Entity & Attributes");
        JMenuItem RelationshipAction = new JMenuItem("Relationship Attributes");
        JMenuItem HelpAction = new JMenuItem("Help");
        JMenuItem AboutAction = new JMenuItem("About");

        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(saveAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exportAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(printAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

        editMenu.add(UndoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(RedoAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(clearAction);

        dbMenu.add(ConvertAction);

        ToolsMenu.add(ColorAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(ZoomAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(EntityAction);
        ToolsMenu.addSeparator();
        ToolsMenu.add(RelationshipAction);

        HelpMenu.add(HelpAction);
        HelpMenu.addSeparator();
        HelpMenu.add(AboutAction);
        
        
        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               
        }}
        );
        
        
        
        
        
        
        ConvertAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
               new ConvertForm().setVisible(true);
                
                
               
        }}
        );
        
        
        

        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                new DrawForm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
       
        JPanel FieldPanel = new JPanel();

        // Swing box that will hold all the buttons

        Box theBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        Box theBoxs = Box.createVerticalBox();

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeButtons by passing the
        // button icon.

        
        lineBut = makeMeButtons("./src/line.png", 2);
        ellipseBut = makeMeButtons("./src/ellipse.png", 3);
        rectBut = makeMeButtons("./src/rectangle.png", 4);

        // Make all the buttons in makeMeColorButton by passing the
        // button icon and true for stroke color or false for fill

        strokeBut = makeMeColorButton("./src/stroke.png", 5, true);


        // Add the fields to the boxs

        

        //theBox.add(brushBut);
        theBox.add(lineBut);
        theBox.add(ellipseBut);
        theBox.add(rectBut);
        theBox.add(strokeBut);
       
        buttonPanel.add(theBox);
        FieldPanel.add(theBoxs);
        

        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(FieldPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));        
        FieldPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,480));
        // Make the drawing area take up the rest of the frame

        // this.add(new DrawingBoard(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final DrawingBoard drawPanel = new DrawingBoard();
        this.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        
        
        
        
        
        exportAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(),
                        drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                drawPanel.paint(g);
                g.dispose();

                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                File theDirectory = new File("C:/Users/Wenda/Desktop");
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(theDirectory);
                FileNameExtensionFilter pngFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "PNG file (*.png)", "png");
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pngFilter);
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(pngFilter);

                int status = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(Lesson49_1.this);

                if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(image, "png",
                                fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image saved to "
                                + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Show the frame
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JButton makeMeButtons(String iconFile, final int actionNum) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

         theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentAction = actionNum;
            }
        });
        return theBut;
    }

    // Spits out buttons based on the image supplied and
    // whether a stroke or fill is to be defined

    public JButton makeMeColorButton(String iconFile, final int actionNum,
            final boolean stroke) {
        JButton theBut = new JButton();
        Icon butIcon = new ImageIcon(iconFile);
        theBut.setIcon(butIcon);

        theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (stroke) {

                    // JColorChooser is a popup that lets you pick a color

                    strokeColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,
                            "Pick a Stroke", Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                                    }
            }
        });

        return theBut;
    }
    public class DrawingBoard extends JComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431176095451940075L;

        // ArrayLists that contain each shape drawn along with
        // that shapes stroke and fill
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        ArrayList<Color> shapeStroke = new ArrayList<Color>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        
        Point drawStart, drawEnd;
        // Monitors events on the drawing area of the frame

        public DrawingBoard() {
            

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (currentAction != 1) {

                        // When the mouse is pressed get x & y position

                        drawStart = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        drawEnd = drawStart;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    int counts =0;
                    if (currentAction != 1) {
                        Shape aShape = null;
                        
                        if (currentAction == 2) {
                            aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                            e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;
                            repaint();
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 3) {
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                             e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;                                                        
                            repaint();
                            counts = counts+1;
                            count.add(counts);
                           int sizes = count.size();
                            System.out.println(sizes);
                             new AttributeForm().setVisible(true);
                        } else

                        if (currentAction == 4) {

                            // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                            aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                            e.getX(), e.getY());
                            shapes.add(aShape);
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;
                            repaint();
                            new EntityForm().setVisible(true);
                        }

                        // Add shapes, fills and colors to there ArrayLists

                                              

                    }

                }
            });
            
              this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                JTextField name = new JTextField(15);
                super.mouseClicked(me);
                for (Shape s : shapes) {

                    if (s.contains(me.getPoint())) {//check if mouse is clicked within shape

                        //we can either just print out the object class name
                        System.out.println("Clicked a "+s.getClass().getName());

                        //or check the shape class we are dealing with using instance of with nested if
                        if (s instanceof Rectangle2D) {
                            
                            //create table  
                            
                        } 
                         else if (s instanceof Ellipse2D) {
                            
                           
                             
                            
                            
                            
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });

            this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                    // If this is a brush have shapes go on the screen quickly

                    if (currentAction == 1) {

                        int x = e.getX();
                        int y = e.getY();

                        Shape aShape = null;
                        shapes.add(aShape);

                        shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);

                        // Add the transparency value
                    }

                    // Get the final x & y position after the mouse is dragged

                    drawEnd = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // Class used to define the shapes to be drawn

            graphSettings = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Antialiasing cleans up the jagged lines and defines rendering
            // rules

            graphSettings.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Defines the line width of the stroke

            graphSettings.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

            // Iterators created to cycle through strokes and fills
            Iterator<Color> strokeCounter = shapeStroke.iterator();
            for (Shape s : shapes) {
 
                // Grabs the next stroke from the color arraylist
                graphSettings.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                graphSettings.draw(s);

            }

            // Guide shape used for drawing
            if (drawStart != null && drawEnd != null) {
                // Makes the guide shape transparent

                graphSettings.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                        AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.40f));

                // Make guide shape gray for professional look

                graphSettings.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

                Shape aShape = null;

                if (currentAction == 2) {
                    aShape = drawLine(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 3) {
                    aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                } else

                if (currentAction == 4) {

                    // Create a new rectangle using x & y coordinates

                    aShape = drawRectangle(drawStart.x, drawStart.y, drawEnd.x,
                            drawEnd.y);
                }

                graphSettings.draw(aShape);
            }
        }

    
        private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
            // Math.min returns the points closest to 0

            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

           private Ellipse2D.Float drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }

        private Line2D.Float drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

            return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
           }
    
    }
```

**Here is my AttributeForm:**

```
public class AttributeForm {
    public static void main (String args[]){

        //if sizes is >1
        System.out.println("Greater than one");

        //else

        System.out.println("Less than one");

    }
}
```

What can you suggest?

Comment: Where are you instantiating the DrawForm class? Inside AttributeForm?

Comment: Infact my drawform is supposed to draw some ellipse and then the sizes will count the number of ellipses, print it but also call the form Attributeform and pass the value of the variable sizes where the form AttributeForm will make an IF-Statement on the variable "sizes" and print it.  The DrawForm is not closed, it will still be ran, i just want it to take the value of variable sizes from the drawform and send it to the AttributeForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both DrawForm and AttributeForm both have their own "main" method, so they are running as 2 completely separate applications.  Since they are 2 separate applications, they cannot access each others variables.  I think you need to remove the "main" methods from both Form classes, and create another class, with a single "main" method, which will then start both DrawForm and AttributeForm. Example:

If you want to retrieve the variable "sizes" from DrawForm, you need a getter for that variable in the DrawForm class

```
//assuming sizes is an integer
public int getSizes(){
  return sizes;
}
```

If you want to set the variable "sizes" on AttributeForm, you need a setter for that variable in the AttributeForm class

```
//assuming sizes is an integer
public void setSizes(int sizes){
  this.sizes = sizes;
}
```

Your AttributeForm might look like this

```
public class AttributeForm {
    int sizes;

    public void setSizes(int sizes){
      this.sizes = sizes;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
      if(this.sizes > 1)
          System.out.println("Greater than one");
        else
          System.out.println("Less than one");
    }
  }
```

And finally, the new class, with one "main" that starts everything

```
public class MyApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DrawForm dform = new DrawForm();
    dform.setVisible(true);
    int sizes = dform.getSizes();

    AttributeForm aform = new AttributeForm();
    aform.setSizes(sizes);
    aform.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Infact my drawform is supposed to draw some ellipse and then the sizes will count the number of ellipses, print it but also call the form Attributeform and pass the value of the variable sizes where the form AttributeForm will make an IF-Statement on the variable "sizes" and print it.  The DrawForm is not closed, it will still be ran, i just want it to take the value of variable sizes from the drawform and send it to the AttributeForm.

Comment: I dont want to open another "DrawForm" but just use the data of the drawform into the attribute form. What can you suggest?

Comment: So, where are you starting DrawForm from.  Does DrawForm have its own  "main" method?  There must be a "main" somewhere that starts the whole application.

Comment: Yes, Both forms have a main method. Here is the main method for the DrawForm 'public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawForm();
    }'  Do you want me to post the whole block of codes for the DrawForm?

Comment: I've edited my post and posted the whole block of codes for the "DrawForm" Can you please check and help?

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is both DrawForm and AttributeForm have "main" methods, so they are running as 2 separate applications.  You need one centralized "main" that starts both forms.